# Regex for path like string

Tags: regex

I need to validate that strings has the following pattern:

```
component/1.2/text
component/1.2.3/othertext
component/1.2.32/text
component/10.21.32/yetanothertext
```

So always contains two path separators, starts with component followed by major.minor or major.minor.bug and ends with some text.

Any suggestion for a regular expression that can be used to discard anything NOT following the above pattern, e.g.:

```
component/4/base
comp/4/samples
...
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: `/^component\/\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}\/\w+$/` ... https://regex101.com/r/aE8cP4/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex. `^component\/\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}\/\w+`

Here's a visualization.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Try demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/uO8jW8/2).

Answer (score 0):

and another soultion:

```
component/([\d\.]{1,2})/\w+
```

Or you can try also with {0,1}, not {1,2}